# Want to translate Django User model first_name and last_name - django 1.5

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-modeltranslation, django-hvad

I want to translate my from django.contrib.auth.models import User Model's first_name and last_name. I am aware of Custom User Model in Django. But is there any better way of translating using [django Hvad](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad)

For reference i am attaching my Model here

```
class UserProfile(TranslatableModel):
    translations = CustomTranslatedFields(

         bio=models.TextField(
             verbose_name=_('Biography'),
             blank=True
         ),

    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='user_profile',
        verbose_name=_('User Profile'),
    )

    default_language = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=LANGUAGES,
        default='en'
    )
```

As you can see bio field is translatable but how would i be able to translate my User models first_name and last_name field

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way Django Hvad defines translatable fields, there is actually no way to do it unless you define your own User model.